# How to get more info regarding Legacy System Extensions in MacOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, extension

With the upgrade to the most recent version of MacOS Catalina 10.15.4 (19E287), I received a handful of warnings about this or that legacy system extension:

[image: MacOS Legacy System Extension pop-up]

- Legacy Developer: Sierrawireless
- Symantec
- Ploytec GmbH
- Legacy Developer: Novatelwireles
- Legacy Developer: Rim
- Legacy Developer: Lge

The "More Info" button takes one to this [Apple Support Page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210999). Some of these look suspiciously old to me, particularly the "Legacy Developer" ones. Rather than "contact[ing] the developer", I'd like to see more information about these extensions and determine two things:

1. Is this extension related to an app (which I may no longer be using)
2. How can I remove, safely, an unwanted system extension.

So, any information on how to dig deeper and act upon into these warnings would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Use System Report

The following worked for me:

1. Click on the Apple icon then **About This Mac**
2. Click on **System Report**
3. In the left column, Click on **Software > Extensions**
4. (Be patient -- it might take a while to load up the info)
5. Click on the **Obtained From** column so you can skip over all the Apple provided extensions
6. Look at each extension NOT provided by Apple.  If the **Dependencies** field is **Deprecated**, you probably can (and should) remove it.

P.S.: A similar technique for **Applications** (see step 3 above) lets you quickly find all 32-bit applications, which will also be unsupported going forward.

Comment: If you see a blank panel, you may want to give the system some time to generate the report.

Comment: Thank you, it was very useful. I have restored a backup from High Sierra old 2011 macbook to a new M2 and got a lot of those warnings about blocked extensions. Did not save those names and spent a lot of time searching logs, etc. to find what they were. Your solution helped to get those from the old laptop to verify what I need to update. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't panic. Your Mac will continue to work fine. Check out these two links. They have good info on the subject:

https://www.idownloadblog.com/2018/06/19/legacy-apps-macos-mojave/

https://www.macrumors.com/2020/03/25/mac-legacy-system-extension-warning/

I was able to find the culprit apps in different folders, and once identified as really useless (RIM for example), I dragged the containing folder to the trash and voilà.

Other apps may just need updating, like Norton and Symantec.

Good luck.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: These links were useless to me.  The first link told me to go to "Legacy Software" to which my Mac says "No information found".